# Question marks on install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a Dell Dimension 8400 with a gigabyte of ram, a 300GB hard drive, and a 3Ghz Pentium 4 processor.

I have one partition already on my computer, this partition is 8GB in size, and has Free-DOS. I use Free-DOS to run old Motorola software, which interfaces with serial. DOS emulators do not work, nor does running the DOS prompt in windows, therefore I need to keep the partition for DOS.

When I boot up, and click the install icon, it prompts me if I want to install on the rest of space, which I do want to do. After proceeding by clicking install, an error pops up.

The error box shows ???? ????, and clicking OK does not do anything (the box is still there)

What steps can I take to solve the problem and successful dual boot Ubuntu and Free-DOS.

I have tried several reboots, and a re-download to the bootable flash drive.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you attemping to install?   64 or 32 bit?  Does "try Ubuntu" work?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the partitions manually instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried manual partitions as well as linuxmint. I am using 32 bit. The hard drives are two 149GB hard drives in an Array.